# How to prevent FB from loudly auto-playing videos? FB settings don't work

Tags: audio, facebook

In Facebook on android I have "Never Autoplay Videos" on and "Videos start with sound" off. Nevertheless, FB autoplays videos with sound. Moreover,

FB version 411.1.0.29.112 on android 10 on samsung galaxy 9+

Comment: Are you open to automation? Apps such as MacroDroid or Tasker can reduce the speaker/media volume to user specified levels when Facebook app is in foreground. When it goes into background the original volume level can be automatically restored too.

Comment: As firelord said.. just to add you can use Automate app too.. it's more light weight than macrodroid and tasker is paid